# How to cache all the data files of mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, caching

What I am trying to do is cache all the data that I have written into mongodb. So that all client requests are served from the cache. Should I consider ehcache or memcache.
Note the mongodb data is queried a lot, that is why I have thought to cache all of it at server start time, no writes are permitted to this data. I am using java for the application.

Comment: Are you actually experiencing performance problems? Have you tried giving more memory to MongoDB?

Comment: No performance problems, just an architecture decision ?

Comment: Why increase the complexity of development and configuration if there isn't a need?

Comment: Actually，in one of my projects, I use the same method hershey92 says, when my Java application starts, I load all the documents from the collection in mongodb, and save them into a java hashmap, after that, all the queries go to the HashMap.my java application and mongodb are on different servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes very little sense to use a cache in front of MongoDB if you are using it for reads only. An extra cache is just going to take up more memory. MongoDB uses memory-mapped files and the Operating System will keep the most requested data in memory. If all of your data fits in memory, then MongoDB will returns all the documents straight from it - just like an additional cache would.

Comment: If the cache is on the same server, I'd agree.

Comment: what if the client queries from a different server